# SQL to look up table and make one record per field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have three tables in my database.

Table one effectively contains two fields:

```
|Datetime| |Set|
```

Table two is a lookup table which matches a number of parts of a set to a set number:

```
|Set| |Part1| |Part2| |Part3| |Part4|
```

I want table 3 to have a record for each part in a set for a particular datetime:

```
|Datetime| |Part|
```

where the populated table would look something like:

```
|12:00:00| |Set1_Part1|
|12:00:00| |Set1_Part2|
|12:00:00| |Set1_Part3|
|12:00:00| |Set1_Part4|
|12:02:30| |Set2_Part1|
|12:02:30| |Set2_Part2|
|12:02:30| |Set2_Part3|
|12:02:30| |Set2_Part4|
```

So I get some information in table 1 about a set and a datetime, then table 3 needs to effectively extrapolate that out into a datetime/part pair for each part in the set.

Any ideas? (This is for SQL Server)

Comment: unpivot it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: always up to ONLY 4 parts?

Comment: No, sometimes it will be 5 parts. Some sets have 4, the rest have 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like...

```
Insert Into table3 (
Select datetime, set + '_' + Part1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
  on T1.Set=T2.Set 
  and Part1 is not null
UNION
Select datetime, set + '_' + Part2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
  on T1.Set=T2.Set
  and Part2 is not null
UNION
Select datetime, set + '_' + Part3
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
  on T1.Set=T2.Set
 and Part3 is not null
UNION
Select datetime, set + '_' + Part4
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
  on T1.Set=T2.Set
 and Part4 is not null
UNION
Select datetime, set + '_' + Part5
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
  on T1.Set=T2.Set
 and Part5 is not null
```

)

Comment: While this works Gordon's solution is a bit cleaner due to the creation of an inline view and only joining back to table 1 once.

Answer (score 1):

The "canonical" way to do this in SQL Server is to use `union all`:

```
select t1.datetime, t2.part
from ((select set, Part1 as part from table2) union all
      (select set, Part2 from table2) union all
      (select set, Part3 from table2) union all
      (select set, Part4 from table2)
     ) t join
     table1 t1
     on t1.set = t.set;
```

You can use the `into table3` clause if you want to store this in another table.  Note that `set` and `datetime` are reserved words so if these are the real names of the columns, they should be square braces.

There are other ways to do this, including `unpivot` (rather specific to SQL Server) and doing a cross join with a conditional.  However, it would be better to normalize `table2`, if you can.  The columns would be:

- Set
- Part
- PartNumber

So one row would become four.

Answer (score 0):

This is another reason why normalization is so important. If you didn't have all your part number strung out as columns this wouldn't be an issue. We can leverage CROSS APPLY here to make short work of this however.

```
create table #Something
(
    SetName varchar(10)
    , Part1 varchar(10)
    , Part2 varchar(10)
    , Part3 varchar(10)
    , Part4 varchar(10)
    , Part5 varchar(10)
)

insert #Something
select 'Set 1', 'Part 1', 'Part 2', 'Part 3', 'Part 4', null union all
select 'Set 2', 'Part 1', 'Part 2', 'Part 3', 'Part 4', 'Part 5' 

select s.SetName, d.Part
from #Something s
cross apply (VALUES (Part1), (Part2), (Part3), (Part4), (Part5)) d (Part)
where d.Part is not null
```